# Confused with Shiny Modules and renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to plot a `dygraph` in my Shiny App but I can't seem to get the output working. I would like to do it using modules.

`Comprar = purchase` and `Alquiler = Rental`.

- I randomly create some price data and some dates
- Generate some summary statistics for the average price and number of observations in the data `comprar_stats` and `alquiler_stats`
- I store some metrics in a list that I would like to call throughout the App.
- Then in `ui_dygraph` I try to generate the dropdown module for each option on my data `comprar_main`, `alquiler_main` and `price_to_rent`. I am able to generate a dropdown but not an output of the dygraph...

How I can I obtain the output of the dygraph? - This code is a mix of some Shiny code I took from the Appsilon "Enterprice Shiny" App - I would like to try and modularise my Apps.

Expected Output: Obtain the `dygraph` outputs depending on the dropdown.

Shiny App:

```
   library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dygraphs)
library(zoo)
################################################################################

startDate <- as.Date("2023-01-01")
endDate <- as.Date("2023-06-01")
dates <- rep(dates, each = 10)
propertyPrices <- round(rnorm(length(dates), mean = 100000, sd = 20000), 2)
comprar_main <- data.frame(collectionDate = dates, price = propertyPrices)
propertyRentals <- round(rnorm(length(dates), mean = 1000, sd = 200), 2)
alquiler_main <- data.frame(collectionDate = dates, price = propertyRentals)


################################################################################

################################################################################

comprar_stats = comprar_main %>%
  filter(collectionDate > as.Date("2022-09-27")) %>%  # accidently have rental data before this date
  filter(price < 1000000) %>%
  filter(price > 100000) %>%
  group_by(collectionDate) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_price = mean(price),
    mean_price = round(mean_price, 0),
    propertiesListed = n()
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    rolling_average = rollapply(mean_price, fill=NA, width = 14, mean, align = "right"),
    rolling_average = round(rolling_average, 0)
  ) %>%
  add_column(
    type = "comprar_main"
  )

alquiler_stats = alquiler_main %>%
  filter(collectionDate > as.Date("2022-09-27")) %>%
  filter(price < 2500) %>%
  filter(price > 200) %>%
  group_by(collectionDate) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_price = mean(price),
    mean_price = round(mean_price, 0),
    propertiesListed = n()
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    rolling_average = rollapply(mean_price, fill=NA, width = 14, mean, align = "right"),
    rolling_average = round(rolling_average, 0)
  ) %>%
  add_column(
    type = "alquiler_main"
  )

stats = bind_rows(comprar_stats, alquiler_stats)

stats_price_to_rent = full_join(comprar_stats, alquiler_stats, by = "collectionDate") %>%
  mutate(
    mean_price = mean_price.x / (mean_price.y * 12), # annualise the rent
    mean_price = round(mean_price),
    rolling_average = rollapply(mean_price, fill=NA, width = 14, mean, align = "right"),
    rolling_average = round(rolling_average, 0),

    propertiesListed = propertiesListed.y / propertiesListed.x,
    propertiesListed = round(propertiesListed, 2)
  ) %>%
  add_column(type = "price_to_rent_main") %>%
  select(c(collectionDate, mean_price, propertiesListed, rolling_average, type))
################################################################################


metrics_list <- list(
  comprar_main = list(
    id = "comprar_main",
    title = "Comprar (All Spain)",
    currency = "€",
    category = "comprar",
    legend = "Purchase Spain",
    legend2 = "# of properties"
  ),
  alquiler_main = list(
    id = "alquiler_main",
    title = "Alquiler (All Spain)",
    currency = "€",
    category = "alquiler",
    legend = "Rental Spain",
    legend2 = "# of properties"
  ),
  price_to_rent_main = list(
    id = "price_to_rent_main",
    title = "Price to Rent (All Spain)",
    currency = "€",
    category = "misc",
    legend = "Price To Rent",
    legend2 = "# of rentals / # of purchases",
    caption = "Some info here"
  )
)


################################################################################

################################################################################
########################### User interfaces ####################################
ui_dygraph <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  # Add all available metrics to dygraph chart
  choices <- names(metrics_list)

  tagList(
    tags$div(
      class = "panel-header",
      selectInput(
        ns("metric"), "Select metric for the time chart",
        choices,
        width = NULL,
        selectize = TRUE,
        selected = choices[[1]]
      )
    ),
    tags$div(
      class = "chart-time-container",
      dygraphOutput(ns("dygraph"), height = "240px")
    )
  )
}
################################################################################

ui <- navbarPage(
  fluidPage(
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "minty"),
    title = "hi",

    ui_dygraph("dygraph"),
    renderUI(output$dygraph)
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session, df) {
  metric <- reactive({ metrics_list[[input$metric]] })

  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({

    data = df

    metric_suffix <- ifelse(!is.null(metric()$currency), glue::glue(" ({metric()$currency})"), "")
    metric_legend <- paste0(metric()$legend, metric_suffix)

    metric_legend2 <- paste0(metric()$legend2)

    if(metric()$id == "comprar_main") {
      dyAxisValueRange = c(220000, 310000)
      dy2AxisValueRange = c(0, 15000)

    } else if (metric()$id == "alquiler_main") {
      dyAxisValueRange = c(0, 2700)
      dy2AxisValueRange = c(0, 4000)

    } else { # price_to_rent_main axis
      dyAxisValueRange = c(15, 35)
      dy2AxisValueRange = c(0, 3.5)

    }

    if (metric()$id == "comprar_main") {
      data = stats
    } else if (metric()$id == "alquiler_main") {
      data = stats
    } else {
      data = stats_price_to_rent
    }


    data %>%
      filter(type == metric()$id) %>%
      select(-c(type)) %>%
      column_to_rownames("collectionDate") %>%
      as.xts() %>%
      # as.xts(order.by = .$collectionDate)
      dygraph(main = glue::glue("{metric()$title}")) %>%
      dySeries("mean_price", label = metric_legend, drawPoints = FALSE, color = "#0099F9") %>%
      dySeries("rolling_average", label = "Rolling Average (14 days)", drawPoints = FALSE, color = "#15354A") %>%
      dyAxis("y", label = "Price", valueRange = dyAxisValueRange, independentTicks = TRUE,
             valueFormatter = 'function(d){return d.toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",");}',
             axisLabelFormatter = 'function(d){return d.toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",");}'
      ) %>%
      dyAxis("y2", label = metric_legend2, valueRange = dy2AxisValueRange, independentTicks = TRUE,
             valueFormatter = 'function(d){return d.toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",");}',
             axisLabelFormatter = 'function(d){return d.toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",");}'
      ) %>%
      dySeries("propertiesListed", label = metric_legend2, stepPlot = TRUE, fillGraph = TRUE, color = "#bdc2c6", axis=('y2')) %>%
      dyOptions(
        includeZero = FALSE,
        axisLineColor = "#585858",
        gridLineColor = "#bdc2c6",
        axisLabelFontSize = 12,
        axisLabelColor = "#585858",
        disableZoom = TRUE
      )
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You need a server module for `ui_dygraph`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @YBS in the comments the issue is that your `digraph` module misses a `moduleServer`. Moving you code from the main server to a module server will fix your issue:

```
library(xts)
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dygraphs)

ui_dygraph <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  choices <- names(metrics_list)

  tagList(
    tags$div(
      class = "panel-header",
      selectInput(
        ns("metric"), "Select metric for the time chart",
        choices,
        width = NULL,
        selectize = TRUE,
        selected = choices[[1]]
      )
    ),
    tags$div(
      class = "chart-time-container",
      dygraphOutput(ns("dygraph"), height = "240px")
    )
  )
}

server_dygraph <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    metric <- reactive({
      metrics_list[[input$metric]]
    })

    output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
      data <- df

      metric_suffix <- ifelse(!is.null(metric()$currency), glue::glue(" ({metric()$currency})"), "")
      metric_legend <- paste0(metric()$legend, metric_suffix)

      metric_legend2 <- paste0(metric()$legend2)

      if (metric()$id == "comprar_main") {
        dyAxisValueRange <- c(220000, 310000)
        dy2AxisValueRange <- c(0, 15000)
      } else if (metric()$id == "alquiler_main") {
        dyAxisValueRange <- c(0, 2700)
        dy2AxisValueRange <- c(0, 4000)
      } else { 
        dyAxisValueRange <- c(15, 35)
        dy2AxisValueRange <- c(0, 3.5)
      }

      if (metric()$id == "comprar_main") {
        data <- stats
      } else if (metric()$id == "alquiler_main") {
        data <- stats
      } else {
        data <- stats_price_to_rent
      }

      data %>%
        filter(type == metric()$id) %>%
        select(-c(type)) %>%
        column_to_rownames("collectionDate") %>%
        as.xts() %>%

        dygraph(main = glue::glue("{metric()$title}")) %>%
        dySeries("mean_price", label = metric_legend, drawPoints = FALSE, color = "#0099F9") %>%
        dySeries("rolling_average", label = "Rolling Average (14 days)", drawPoints = FALSE, color = "#15354A") %>%
        dyAxis("y",
          label = "Price", valueRange = dyAxisValueRange, independentTicks = TRUE,
          valueFormatter = 'function(d){return d.toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",");}',
          axisLabelFormatter = 'function(d){return d.toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",");}'
        ) %>%
        dyAxis("y2",
          label = metric_legend2, valueRange = dy2AxisValueRange, independentTicks = TRUE,
          valueFormatter = 'function(d){return d.toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",");}',
          axisLabelFormatter = 'function(d){return d.toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",");}'
        ) %>%
        dySeries("propertiesListed", label = metric_legend2, stepPlot = TRUE, fillGraph = TRUE, color = "#bdc2c6", axis = ("y2")) %>%
        dyOptions(
          includeZero = FALSE,
          axisLineColor = "#585858",
          gridLineColor = "#bdc2c6",
          axisLabelFontSize = 12,
          axisLabelColor = "#585858",
          disableZoom = TRUE
        )
    })
  })
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  fluidPage(
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "minty"),
    title = "hi",
    ui_dygraph("dygraph")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session, df) {
  server_dygraph("dygraph")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]